# Syntactically Incorrect request Spring MVC form

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a form that has three fields.
I want to receive those fields in a spring controller as individual request parameters.

but in my case, if i am leaving one field blank, it is throwing me error that syntactically incorrect request.

```
<form:form method="post" action="submitQuery">

            <input type="text" maxlength="7" id="field1" name="field1"/> 
            <input type="text" id="field2" name="field2" /> 
            <input type="text" id="field3" name="field3" />

            <input type="submit" name="filter" value="Filter"/>
</form:form>
```

> Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submitQuery" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String inboundSearchResult(@RequestParam String field1, @RequestParam(required=false) String field2 , @RequestParam(required=false) String field3 , Model model){

        ..
        ..
        return "intendedView";
    }
```

How can i send those fields to the controller? and for me all three fields are not mandatory. 
If somebody fill only one field, then too the form should be submitted.
Please help.

Comment: Which field is left blank? Post the stacktrace of your error.

Comment: well.. it is working now. Surprisingly it was not working before. I am extremely sorry for wasting your time.